# Yii2 app\model\Db6TrxImportData not found

Tags: php, yii2

I am new with Yii2 and i am having this error.

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Class 'app\models\Db6TrxImportData' not found

I have searched somewhere that you need to add

> use app\models\Db6TrxImportData;

i have already added this to my controller but still get the same error. I am noob in yii2.. please help. This is my code.

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\dtv\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\components\helpers\User;
use app\components\helpers\Data;
use app\models\Db6TrxImportData;

class ManageController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    // Properties
    public $layout = '/registerLayout';
    public $breadcrumbItems;
    public $breadcrumbHomeItems;
    public $route_nav = 'dtv/manage/list';
    public $viewPath = 'app/modules/dtv/views';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['list', 'delete'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['list', 'delete'],
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                        'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                            $identity = User::initUser();
                            $feature = Yii::$app->params['Modules']['News Video Management'];
                            return User::hasAccess($identity, $feature);
                        },
                    ],
                ],
                'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                        $this->goHome();
                    } else {
                        $this->redirect(['/dashboard']);
                    }
                }
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function init()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $label  = Yii::t('app', 'Login');
            $url    = '/login';
        } else {
            $label  = Yii::t('app', 'Dashboard');
            $url    = '/dashboard';
        }

        $this->breadcrumbHomeItems = [
            'label' => $label,
            'url'     => $url,
            'template' => '<li>{link}</li> ',
        ];
    }

    public function actionList()
    {
        // Initialize Layout
        $this->breadcrumbItems = [
            Yii::t('app', 'Xml acquisition article list')
        ];

        $identity = User::initUser();
        $ownerId  = User::getOwnerId($identity);

        $dtvMovieModel = new Db6TrxImportData();

        $params = [ 'owner'         => $ownerId,
                    'status'        => 'active',
                    'application'   => 'menumaker'
                  ];
        $dtvMovie = $dtvMovieModel->getRecords($params);

        return $this->render('list', [
            'dtvMovie' => $dtvMovie
        ]);

    }

}       
?>
```

This is my Model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\Query;
use app\components\helpers\User;
use app\components\helpers\Data;
    
class Db6TrxImportData extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '_dtvdb.trx_import_data';
    }

    public static function getDb()
    {
        return Yii::$app->get('dtvdb');
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['article_id', 'ctrl_flg', 'image_flg', 'video_flg', 'del_flg', 'news_cat', 'news_cat_cd', 'copyright', 'copyright_cd', 'title', 'article_text', 'zapping_text'], 'required'],
            [['cx_create_date', 'cx_update_date', 'publish_date_from', 'publish_date_to', 'import_date', 'create_time', 'up_time'], 'safe'],
            [['status'], 'string'],
            [['article_id'], 'string', 'max' => 12],
            [['ctrl_flg', 'image_flg', 'video_flg', 'del_flg'], 'string', 'max' => 1],
            [['news_cat', 'news_sub_cat', 'disptach_type', 'copyright', 'lang'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['news_cat_cd', 'dispatch_cd', 'copyright_cd', 'lang_cd', 'article_status', 'zapping_status'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
            [['news_sub_cat_cd'], 'string', 'max' => 4],
            [['title', 'zapping_text'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
            [['article_text'], 'string', 'max' => 1000],
            [['comment'], 'string', 'max' => 500]
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'article_id' => 'Article ID',
            'cx_create_date' => 'Cx Create Date',
            'cx_update_date' => 'Cx Update Date',
            'ctrl_flg' => 'Ctrl Flg',
            'image_flg' => 'Image Flg',
            'video_flg' => 'Video Flg',
            'del_flg' => 'Del Flg',
            'news_cat' => 'News Cat',
            'news_cat_cd' => 'News Cat Cd',
            'news_sub_cat' => 'News Sub Cat',
            'news_sub_cat_cd' => 'News Sub Cat Cd',
            'dispatch_cd' => 'Dispatch Cd',
            'disptach_type' => 'Disptach Type',
            'copyright' => 'Copyright',
            'copyright_cd' => 'Copyright Cd',
            'lang_cd' => 'Lang Cd',
            'lang' => 'Lang',
            'publish_date_from' => 'Publish Date From',
            'publish_date_to' => 'Publish Date To',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'article_text' => 'Article Text',
            'comment' => 'Comment',
            'zapping_text' => 'Zapping Text',
            'import_date' => 'Import Date',
            'article_status' => 'Article Status',
            'zapping_status' => 'Zapping Status',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'create_time' => 'Create Time',
            'up_time' => 'Up Time',
        ];
    }
    
    public static function findByAttribute($arr)
    {
        foreach ($arr as $arrKey => $arrValue) {
            $record = self::find()->where($arrKey.'=:'.$arrKey,[':'.$arrKey => $arrValue])->one();
        }
        return $record;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the file defining the class? Could u post the content of that file?

Comment: did you mean the model.?

Comment: i have edited my question and added the model class..

Comment: make sure you don't have any typos in model name.

Comment: i don't have typos i think. i really copied the name..

Comment: It should work no any errors back then.

Comment: Where is the model class file? Is it under app/models?

Comment: yes it is under app/models

Comment: look if your filename has the same name otherwise it isn't loaded. Linux also tests for case sensitivity so it must be named `Db6TrxImportData.php` and the classname in that file must also be `Db6TrxImportData`.

Comment: list your app directory.. maybe the problem is in there

Comment: Hi everyone. Im sorry for the confusion. This is actually correct. the problem however is in my server. it was not properly sync. That is why some files where not found. sorry about that. My stupid mistake.